# Count integers in file and copy to dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, file

I'm currently programming a program using the a-star algorithm. Therefore I generate a random maze and save it in a .txt file. The file looks a bit like this:

```
19999999199999991
19191119111919191
```

where a `1` is a wall, and a `9` is a blank space.

Now I have to read the file into a *findpath program*, which takes the file and reads it into a array. Then the program calculates the shortest path.

---

When I just copy the integers of the file to the source code everything works fine. But now I want to make the program more dynamically, therefore; I would like to read in the file, calculate the needed size of the array and store the integers in the array, all at once.

My big problem now is that I don't know how to read in the file and get the size of the maze.

For my functions I would have to calculate the number of rows and columns in the file, generate the array and store the integers in the array, but I don't have a clue how to do this. One problem of mine is that the integers aren't separated by a blank, and I can't change my program, which generates the file.

I already know how to open the file, but;

- How can I get the size of the file (the number of integers in a row, and the number of rows), and;
- how can I store the integers separately in an array?

**Edit:**

So I updated my program with the following code:

```
main
{
     ifstream myfile("BLOCK_style_maze.txt");
     string line;
     int colCount=0;
     int rowCount=0;
     int temp=0;

     if(myfile.is_open())
     {
        if(getline(myfile,line))
        {
            rowCount++;
            int i=0;
            for(i=0;i<line.length();i++)
            {
                 if(line.at(i)=='1' || line.at(i)=='9') colCount++;
            }
        }
        while(getline(myfile, line))
        {
            rowCount++;
        }
        cout << "R:"<< rowCount << "C:" << colCount << endl;
        myfile.close();
     }
     else
     {
        cout << "Unabale to open maze file";
     }

     MAP_WIDTH = colCount;
     MAP_HEIGHT = rowCount;

     map=new int [MAP_WIDTH*MAP_HEIGHT];
     int k=MAP_WIDTH*MAP_HEIGHT;
     int j=0;

     if (myfile.is_open())
     {
        while(myfile >> temp)
        {
           map[j++] = temp;
        }
     }

     for(int i=0; i<=k; i++ )
     {
        cout << map[i]<< endl;
     }
}
```

To test the code I wanted to print the entries of the matrix map on the console, but I just get `0` as output. So I'm a bit confused what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: std::vector is your fried. You don't need to tell him the size of anything and it just.... works :D

Answer (score 0):

A combinaison of `std::vector` and its `push_back` function would do the trick. No need to precompute the size of the maze.

Since you seem unfamiliar with `std::vector` I highly recommend to do the exercise on your own. However, I put [here](http://pastebin.com/h9P159G9) one (of many) solution that extensively use the STL, including `std::stringstream`, `std::copy`, `std::back_inserter` and `std::getline`. I also show how to get the number of row and column. Note that I also use C++11 feature like for-range and `auto`.

Comment: My problem is that I need the MAP_Width and MAP_Height for my future computing. Therefor I need to calculate these two variables. And can you tell me the diverenc between a array and a std::vector. I'm using some code I got to solve the maze and just adapt it to my needings. I'm not really allowed to change alot in the code. So that's why I'm specially asking for an array.

Comment: @user3794592: you don't need to know the width and height before reading the map file, do you? So you can just get the vectors' sizes after reading the file.

Comment: @user3794592, Christian said it very well: use `std::vector::size` member function to get the number of rows and columns.

Comment: @user3794592 I've updated the answer to add more tips and a possible solution. hth

Comment: It seems to me that this is a homework assignment in which he cannot use STL.

Comment: @Optox I really hope that's not the case... That would be a terrible way of learning C++.

Comment: @Optox+Hiura It's not a homework assignment. It's for myself for learning c++. The reason I can't use std::vector is that I use a program found in the web to solve a maze by a-star. The original program worked just with the maze in the source code. So I'm trying to generate the maze, store the maze in a file and the execute the program findpath solves the maze.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a very hard task, try something like the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  string line;
  ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
  int colCount = 0;
  int rowCount = 0;
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    if (getline(myfile,line)) //Read the first line to get the number of columns
    {
      rowCount++; //make sure we count the first line as a row
      int i = 0;
      for (i=0;i<line.length();i++)
      {
         if (line.at(i) == '1' or line.at(i) == '9') colCount++; //each 1 or 9 means a column, we want to ignore other characters like '\n' or spaces
      }
    }
    while (getline(myfile,line)) //Read the rest of the lines to get the rest of the rows.
    {
      rowCount++;
    }
    myfile.close();
  }
  cout << "rows=" << rowCount << '\n';
  cout << "cols=" << colCount << '\n';
  // now that we've counted, let's define our arrays and reopen the file. 
  char** map = new char*[rowCount];
  for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; ++i)
  {
     map[i] = new char[colCount];  
  }

  int currentRow = 0;
  ifstream myfile2 ("example.txt");
  if (myfile2.is_open())
  {
     while(getline(myfile2,line))
     {
       for (int i=0;i<colCount;i++)
       {
         map[currentRow][i] = line.at(i);
       }
       currentRow++;
     }
  }

  // you can now access this array as a 2d array. point = map[row][column]
  for(int i=0;i<colCount;i++){
     cout << map[0][i]; //Print the first row!
  }
  cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where do you store the maze information? Never mind the row and column count -- you need to put all your 1s and 9s somewhere, and once you have done that, determining the size of the maze is trivial.

Comment: I hit save before I'd finished. I open the file a second time after I've allocated the 2D array. I understand that vectors are clearly the 'correct' way to do this, but dynamic allocation of arrays is a very important concept for low-level programming and it also directly answers his question, rather than the standard "you're doing it wrong" answer.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile and most importantly it leaks.

Comment: I'll admit i don't have a compiler at hand, but it still serves as an example. The memory is freed when the program ends. A memory leak happens when you lose track of a pointer to a block of memory.

Comment: fixed it, I checked that it now compiles and works on an example.

Comment: @Optox Why do you read the entire file _twice_, once to measure, once to use, instead of just pushing the thing line by line into a vector of vectors? Your code isn't even really "low-level" -- if you're using a std::ifstream I suggest using high-level containers as well. Things like char** are for _actual_ low-level stuff close to the metal.